# Dart: How I can get length of Stream?

Tags: dart, rxdart

I want to get length of BehaviorSubject's stream, but I can't get it.

```
test('get stream length', ()async{
    BehaviorSubject<int> subject = new BehaviorSubject(seedValue: 0);

    var act = await subject.stream.length;

    expect(act, 1);
  });
```

How I can get this length?

Answer (score 2):

The length of a stream can only be known after it is closed. As long as it is not closed it's always possible that another event will be added.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-async/Stream/length.html

> ### length property
>
> `Future<int> length`
>
> The number of elements in this
>   stream.
>
> Waits for all elements of this stream. When this stream ends, the
>   returned future is completed with the number of elements.
>
> If this stream emits an error, the returned future is completed with
>   that error, and processing stops.
>
> This operation listens to this stream, and a non-broadcast stream
>   cannot be reused after finding its length.

```
  test('get stream length', ()async{
    BehaviorSubject<int> subject = new BehaviorSubject(seedValue: 0);

    var actFuture = await subject.stream.length;
    await subject.close();

    expect(actFuture, completion(equals(1));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to know length of stream to get latest value of another stream with ''' anotherStream.elementAt(length); ''' , is this impossible? Should I try to another way?

Comment: You can't get `elementAt(x)` from a stream that easily. What if that element was emitted earlier already? A stream is like a dripping tap. You don't know in advance how many drops will come down. You can collect the drops (in a `List` for example) and then later use them. There might be better ways for your concrete use case but it's not clear what exactly you try to accomplish.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. It is really easy to understand.

Comment: I try to add <Something> to latest element of List<Something> stream in <Something> stream, I want to use it like Firestore snapshot. But I might should not be use stream in stream...

Comment: The rxdart package provides lots of functionality to do all kinds of things with streams, but you need to adjust your thinking. A stream is not a collection, it's a series of events stretched over some time or over "infinite" time.

Comment: You are right. I should learn stream... I appreciate for the advice.  (and I found `combineLatest2` method, I'll try it.)

Comment: There is a dedicated Gitter channel for rxdart https://gitter.im/ReactiveX/rxdart